# @singledispatchmethod is not working correctly

Tags: python, python-3.8

@singledispatchmethod is not working correctly. I have this code

```
class Stream:
    @singledispatchmethod
    def subscribe(self, arg_1, arg_2):
        pass

    @subscribe.register
    def _(self, msg_type: type, action: Callable):
        pass

    @subscribe.register
    def _(self, msg_type: type, context: bool):
        pass


def aaa() -> None:
    pass


@pytest.mark.asyncio
async def test_can_subscribe_to_specific_event_types():
    stream = Stream()
    stream.subscribe(type(str), aaa)
```

I want to call an overload of a method that takes

```
def _(self, msg_type: type, action: Callable):
```

but python calls

```
def _(self, msg_type: type, context: bool):
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: from the docs `To define a generic function, decorate it with the @singledispatch decorator. When defining a function using @singledispatch, note that the dispatch happens on the type of the first argument:`. You will need to switch the order of your arguments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[From the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.singledispatchmethod)

> When defining a function using @singledispatchmethod, note that the
> **dispatch happens on the type of the first non-self or non-cls
> argument**

In your case it is `msg_type`.